# What is a cast with extensions and without extensions

Tags: c++, types, casting

I've read in [Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (my emphasis):

> When the *C-style cast expression* is encountered, the compiler attempts
> to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> 1. `const_cast<target-type>(expression)`;
> 2. `static_cast<target-type>(expression)`, **with extensions**: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to
>    pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even
>    if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the
>    private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to
>    member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> 3. `static_cast` (**with extensions**) followed by `const_cast`;
> 4. `reinterpret_cast<target-type>(expression)`;
> 5. `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.

What does "with extensions" mean in items 2 and 3?
If possible, I would like an example of cast with extensions and without extensions (if any).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means extending the functionality of `static_cast` as it says:

> pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;

For example:

```cpp
class A {};

class B : private A {};
```

You cannot do so:

```cpp
B b;
A* a = static_cast<A*>(&b); // It's not allowed to convert to inaccessible base class A.
```

But you can:

```cpp
A* a = (A*)(&b);
```

Comment: I think  i got it know. Thanks for your help o_oTurtle